# High WAITING TIME for CSS files on server. How to reduce it?

Tags: css, server, web

the page loading time for the login page is itself 761ms. When I checked, the waiting time for the CSS files is only high. What can I do to reduce that wait time? 
[image]

Comment: including css at the bottom of the page or in the head?

Comment: @PraveenPuglia css is in the head

Comment: Think the initial markup deliver is taking the first 0.2s. Right when the document is received, all css requests are fired at once.. which seems right to me. it's probably the markup delivery time you need to reduce. CSS is doing just fine.

Comment: It looks as if the request for the document is as long as for the css files. Therefore I don't think there's an issue with css, but something more general.

Comment: it looks like there is no issue at all. As all files are loaded in parallel, it share the transfer and so, it will be loaded in such a speed

Comment: @PraveenPuglia actually that is happening for js files too that are on the server. cdn ones are working fine but rest of the files have a high waiting time. What might cause this and what can be the solution?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer actually that is happening for js files too that are on the server. cdn ones are working fine but rest of the files have a high waiting time. What might cause this and what can be the solution?

Comment: @SagarV ok. but it is increasing the page load time quite alot, which is why i want to reduce it if possible

Comment: What is your hosting like? Maybe it's just a low quality web host?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer its AWS

Comment: what is the url

Comment: @SagarV https://cloud.arya.ai

Comment: your script is taking too much time for me

Comment: @SagarV any idea on how can i reduce the loading time and waiting time? Ive been trying alot.

Comment: @SagarV checking the detailed link. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You will get an Idea from this [Facebook pipeline a.k.a BigPipe]

**CLIENT**

1. Browser sends an HTTP request to web server.
2. Web server parses the request, pulls data from storage tier then
   formulates an HTML document and sends it to the client in an HTTP
   response.
3. HTTP response is transferred over the Internet to browser.
4. Browser parses the response from web server, constructs a DOM tree
   representation of the HTML document, and downloads CSS and
   JavaScript resources referenced by the document.
5. After downloading CSS resources, browser parses them and applies
   them to the DOM tree.
6. After downloading JavaScript resources, browser parses and executes
   them.

**SERVER**

1. Request parsing: web server parses and sanity checks the HTTP
   request.
2. Data fetching: web server fetches data from storage tier.
3. Markup generation: web server generates HTML markup for the
   response.
4. Network transport: the response is transferred from web server to
   browser.
5. CSS downloading: browser downloads CSS required by the page.
6. DOM tree construction and CSS styling: browser constructs DOM tree
   of the document, and then applies CSS rules on it.
7. JavaScript downloading: browser downloads JavaScript resources
   referenced by the page.
8. JavaScript execution: browser executes JavaScript code of the page.

This is the idea behind Facebook Pipeline which they implemented to increase the speed.

**In Short**

- split the page to multiple div's
- Load the basic layout and a loader JavaScript file.
- in that JavaScript file, add the required JS and CSS file names and then append it dynamically using DOM or using XHR, add the response text to the main page.
- By using this, a basic page will be loaded and within 1 or 2 second(if it is a faster connection), the actual page will be loaded.

You can read more about Facebook Pipeline [Here](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919/)

Comment: for internal pages can try doing that. But on the login page there are hardly any components that can be split. That page itself is taking a big load time

Comment: you can split it too if you want

Comment: there is only one login form in it. no other components.

Comment: i checked the url and I found 5 css, 5 js and 1 image file. you can see it in sources tab in developer tools.

Comment: yes.  so how do i load them then. the js files are interdependent.

Comment: first load a single JavaScript file. in it, type like `var js1=document.createElement('script'); js1.src="file.js"; document.body.appendChild(js1);` etc, etc.